# Execute an arithmetic expression in Android

Tags: android, arithmetic-expressions

I want to do an arithmetic operation on data stored in an Array. 
User may choose random column and random operation on them. 
like,

```
String DataTmp[10][3] = ...;
String strCalc = "Float.parseFloat(DataTmp[i][0]) + Float.parseFloat(DataTmp[i][2]) * Float.parseFloat(DataTmp[i][1])";
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

**Edited:**
The calculation mentioned above is for example. It is not the fixed calculation.
It may change anyway like,

```
String strCalc = "Float.parseFloat(DataTmp[i][1]) / Float.parseFloat(DataTmp[i][2])";
```

or

```
String strCalc = "(Float.parseFloat(DataTmp[i][2]) - Float.parseFloat(DataTmp[i][1])) / Float.parseFloat(DataTmp[i][1])";
```

So i can't just do that dynamic calculate.
I need to execute the expression inside the String.

**Further Edited:**

User have a textbox to enter the calculation.
So, the user will enter something like "(field 1 - field 3)/field 2" or anything as they wish.
I need to take the corresponding value for fields from array and apply the operation (+,-,*,/) as per the user's selection. 
Everything in this expression is dynamic, including the field order and operations.

---

**Solution Implemented:**
here is the long possible solution i reached. add improvements if you've any.
i didn't implement the hierarchy of calculation based on parenthesis.

```
              strCalc = strCalc.replace("(", "");
              strCalc = strCalc.replace(")", "");

              List<String> calcList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(strCalc
                          .split(" ")));
              showInfo("List Size : " + calcList.size());
              // Doing multiplication and division first
              for (int i = 0; i < calcList.size(); i++) {
                    String curStr = calcList.get(i);
                    if (curStr.compareTo("*") == 0) {
                          float val1 = Float.parseFloat(calcList.get(i - 1));
                          float val2 = Float.parseFloat(calcList.get(i + 1));
                          calcList.remove(i - 1);
                          calcList.remove(i - 1);
                          calcList.remove(i - 1);
                          float result = val1 * val2;
                          calcList.add(i - 1, "" + result);
                          i--;
                          continue;
                    }
                    if (curStr.compareTo("/") == 0) {
                          float val1 = Float.parseFloat(calcList.get(i - 1));
                          float val2 = Float.parseFloat(calcList.get(i + 1));
                          calcList.remove(i - 1);
                          calcList.remove(i - 1);
                          calcList.remove(i - 1);
                          float result = val1 / val2;
                          calcList.add(i - 1, "" + result);
                          i--;
                          continue;
                    }
              }
              // Doing addition and subtraction next
              for (int i = 0; i < calcList.size(); i++) {
                    String curStr = calcList.get(i);
                    if (curStr.compareTo("+") == 0) {
                          float val1 = Float.parseFloat(calcList.get(i - 1));
                          float val2 = Float.parseFloat(calcList.get(i + 1));
                          calcList.remove(i - 1);
                          calcList.remove(i - 1);
                          calcList.remove(i - 1);
                          float result = val1 + val2;
                          calcList.add(i - 1, "" + result);
                          i--;
                          continue;
                    }
                    if (curStr.compareTo("-") == 0) {
                          float val1 = Float.parseFloat(calcList.get(i - 1));
                          float val2 = Float.parseFloat(calcList.get(i + 1));
                          calcList.remove(i - 1);
                          calcList.remove(i - 1);
                          calcList.remove(i - 1);
                          float result = val1 - val2;
                          calcList.add(i - 1, "" + result);
                          i--;
                          continue;
                    }
              }
              return calcList.get(0);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Answer (score 0):

The way you chose should work

```
float result = Float.parseFloat(DataTmp[i][0]) + Float.parseFloat(DataTmp[i][2]) * Float.parseFloat(DataTmp[i][1]);
String strCalc = String.valueOf(result);
```

But you need to be careful: make sure you actually have floats in your `DataTmp` array (by checking them before doing the operation), and you may also want add some formatting to the result.

Comment: the calculation part i mentioned is not a fixed one.
i've updated my problem.
thanks for replying.

Comment: Your update doesn't really address the problem: do you mean that the operations to do are themselves dynamic? Are you trying to code a calculator or something like that? If so you'd need a reference to the operations you want to do (possibly in an enum), and do the relevant operations according to the user's choice. Please explain in a bit more details what you are exactly trying to achieve

Comment: "the operations to do are themselves dynamic" - this is what i'm trying to achieve.
user have a textbox to enter the calculation.
so, the user will enter something like "(field 1 - field 3)/field 2" or anything as they wish.
i need to take the corresponding value for fields from array and apply the operation (+,-,*,/) as per the user's selection.

Comment: OK, so you need to parse the user input, extract operations and operands, and apply that - it's a lot more complex, I would suggest test-driving it and adding support for different operations iteratively. I may want to think of something and post a new answer.

Comment: ok Guillaume. i thought iterative way will be complex, thats why i asked the question. now, with no other option, i'm going to implement that. let me know if you come up with any solution. Thanks for you attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Index the random column and row in the DataTmp array and then just do the calculation. Make sure you are casting correctly since you are using string arrays.

Comment: "then just do the calculation" - prolink007
doing the calculation is the problem.
seems my problem is unclear. i've corrected it now.
thanks for replying.

Comment: "I need to execute the expression inside the String." - why? You could do what Guillaume suggested and do the calculation and then convert it to string and set it then. What is wrong with that?